# Magento Search Suggestions include ASCII values

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I\\’m having an issue in my store website.. whenever users perform a search, the search suggestions include some special characters something like
`&nbsp;`, `&pound;`, etc
i guess the search engine does not convert above mentioned keywords into symbolic characters. How do i fix the issue? Please refer to the attached screen shot. Thanks in advance.

I'm using Magento 1.5

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the solution.. 
The problem was i was using `$this->htmlEscape(strip_tags($_product->getShortDescription()))` to populate the date for the search suggestion.. i just wrapped it with the function `html_entity_decode()` as it allows ASCII values to be visible in a symbolic view. So my final code was `html_entity_decode($this->htmlEscape((strip_tags($_product->getShortDescription()))))`
to fix the issue.